# <> And Not In VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, operators, query-string

I'm having the exciting task of finding out about VB.NET's `<>` and `Not` operators.  `Not` - I'm assuming by my small use of it - is the functional equivalent of `!` in languages such as C# and `<>` being equivalent of `!=`.

In VB.NET a common problem is doing Boolean expressions against objects that don't have a reference, it appears.  So if we do

```
If Request.QueryString("MyQueryString") <> Nothing Then
```

This will actually fail if the query string doesn't exist.  Why, I don't know.  The way that it's done by older coders is as follows:

```
If Not Request.QueryString("MyQueryString") Is Nothing Then
```

And this tends to work.  To me they're functionally equivalent though operators tend to do different comparisons dependent on certain factors such as operator precedence, why it doesn't work in this case however, I do not know, and neither have I found any relevant material.

I ask this as I'm having to write standards documentation and we're determining the use of either the `Not` or `<>`.  Any ideas on which way around it should be, or you *should* do it?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

I have always used the following:

```
If Request.QueryString("MyQueryString") IsNot Nothing Then
```

But only because syntactically it reads better.

When testing for a valid QueryString entry I also use the following:

```
If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.QueryString("MyQueryString")) Then
```

These are just the methods I have always used so I could not justify their usage other than they make the most sense to me when reading back code.

Comment: So just for clarification, what's the difference between these two?  IsNot Nothing is checking for a null reference I assume, but the latter example also checks for emptiness or a null `value` as opposed to reference?

Comment: Excellent answer, @Charles. Almost identical to what I would've written. +1

Comment: Kezzer - The top one is merely checking for an unpopulated variable e.g. null/nothiing. It would not detect an empty string, I guess the second one is a more complete statement and does more work for you.

Answer (score 11):

`Is` is not the same as `=` -- `Is` compares the references, whilst `=` will compare the values.

If you're using v2 of the .Net Framework (or later), there is the `IsNot` operator which will do the right thing, and read more naturally.

Comment: Oh crap, that'll teach me for assuming equality semantics - it means I just swapped one bug for another in a project at work. I _wish_ we used version control...

Answer (score 10):

I think your question boils down to "the difference between (`Is` and `=`) and also (`IsNot` and <>)".

The answer in both cases is the same :

`=` and `<>` are implicitly defined for value types and you can explicitly define them for your types.

`Is` and `IsNot` are designed for comparisons between reference types to check if the two references refer to the same object.

In your example, you are comparing a string object to Nothing (Null) and since the `=`/`<>` operators are defined for strings, the first example works. However, it does not work when a Null is encountered because Strings are reference types and can be Null. The better way (as you guessed) is the latter version using `Is`/`IsNot`.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the technical answer (expanding on Rowland Shaw's answer).

The *Is* keyword checks whether the two operands are references to the same object memory, and only returns true if this is the case. I believe it is functionally equivalent to *Object.ReferenceEquals*. The *IsNot* keyword is simply shorthand syntax for writing `Not ... Is ...`, nothing more.

The *=* (equality) operator compares values and in this case (as in many others) is equivalent to *String.Equals*. Now, the *<>* (inequality) operator does not quite have the same analogy as the *Is* and *IsNot* keywords, since it can be overriden separately from the *=* operator depending on the class. I believe the case should always be that it returns the logical inverse of the *=* operator (and certainly is in the case of String), and just allows for a more efficient comparison to made when testing for inequality rather than equality.

When dealing with strings, unless you actually mean to compare references, always use the *=* operator (or String.Equals I suppose). In your case, because you are testing for null (*Nothing*), it seems you need to use the *Is* or *IsNot* keyword (the equality operator will fail because it can't compare the values of null objects). Syntactically, the *IsNot* keyword is a bit nicer here, so go with that.

Answer (score 0):

Just use which sounds better.
I'd use the first approach, though, because it seems to have fewer operations.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to know if the variable exists use Is/IsNot Nothing.

Using <> requires that the variable you're evaluating have the "<>" operator defined.
Check out

```
 Dim b As HttpContext
 If b <> Nothing Then
    ...
 End If
```

and the resultant error

```
Error   1   Operator '<>' is not defined for types 'System.Web.HttpContext' and 'System.Web.HttpContext'.
```

Answer (score 0):

The C# and VB.NET compilers often generate different IL for operations that are apparently equivalent in both languages. It just so happens that C# does the "expected" thing when you write `stringvar == null`, but VB.NET does not. To get the same effect in VB.NET you have to force true reference equality with the `Is` operator.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a total noob, I came here to figure out VB's 'not equal to' syntax, so I figured I'd throw it in here in case someone else needed it:

```
<%If Not boolean_variable%>Do this if boolean_variable is false<%End If%>
```

Answer (score 0):

in fact the Is is really good, since to the developpers, you may want to override  the operator ==, to compare with the value.
say you have a class A, operator == of A is to compare some of the field of A to the parameter. then you will be in trouble in c# to verify whether the object of A is null with following code,

```
    A a = new A();
...
    if (a != null)
it will totally wrong, you always need to use if((object)a != null)
but in vb.net you cannot write in this way, you always need to write
    if not a is nothing then
or
    if a isnot nothing then
```

which just as Christian said, vb.net does not 'expected' anything.